# android sqlite query returns cursor with 0 results

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I do call an AsyncTask passing a method to be executed, to be certain a method that returns a row named `NAME` from a specific id. upon calling database query/raw query on doInBackground  it returns a cursor with null results even tried with query `SELECT * FROM TABLE` when TABLE has 8 records. What's the problem here? Is the query unsynchronised?  if it is, how should I code it to prevent these kind of problems?

`EDIT`

```
...
final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

dao.retrieveMovieByIdAsync(1, new AsyncTaskCaller() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Movie result) {
        tv.setText(result.get_Name());
    }});
...

private class AsyncRetieveQuery extends AsyncTask<Method, Void, Movie>
{
    private Object args;
    private AsyncTaskCaller signal;

    public AsyncRetieveQuery(Object args, AsyncTaskCaller signal) {
        this.args = args;
        this.signal = signal;
    }

    @Override
    protected Movie doInBackground(Method... params) {
        params[0].setAccessible(true);
        try {
            return (Movie) params[0].invoke(DBUtils.this, new Object[] {args});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Movie result) {
        signal.execute(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
...
public void retrieveMovieByIdAsync(int id, AsyncTaskCaller resultMethod)
{
    try {
        new AsyncRetieveQuery(id,resultMethod).execute(DBUtils.class.getDeclaredMethod("retrieveMovieById", int.class));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {}
}
...
private Movie retrieveMovieById(int id)
{
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_MOVIES_NAME + " WHERE _Id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
```

Debugger always shows it with null results

Comment: if you set the 2nd parameter of rawQuery() to null, does your cursor still return 0 results? Also, have you tried getting rid of the WHERE clause? It's not really needed in your query right?

Comment: i got rid off the where clause, and still got 0 results...

Comment: when I try to add the same movies in my database i get sqlexception with primakey must be unique, so I assume these entries where recorded to the database, about the second parameter you mean i get rid of the `?` and replace it with the id variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the actual problem is that I had to call `cursor.moveToFirst()` even when I needed only to get the count of the rows from the answer.
I think that when google said the cursor after the query call gets the last result, they maybe meant the null row which you check with the `isAfterLast` method when you iterate the rows.